# Does the increase or decrease of a pure liquid in an equilibrium system have an effect on the direction of equilibrium?

Tags: equilibrium

My textbook reads:

> Although pure liquids have no effect on the equilibrium constant, *K* , pure liquids *can* affect the direction of equilibrium, according to LeChatelier's principle.

Whereas the Organic Chemistry Tutor, in [this video (timestamped)](https://youtu.be/bNcTt3l3Q8k?t=471),states that pure liquids, along with solids, have no effect on the direction of equilibrium.

So which one is true, if either?

Answer (score 1):

If anything but the amount of pure liquid is constant, the position of equilibrium remains constant.

If a change of the amount of pure liquid changes other relevant parameters like e.g. partial pressures, the position of equilibrium shifts.